# Calling interface method C#

Tags: c#, interface, virtual

I am developing an ASP.net MVC application and I have a controller `ExceptionController` for displaying exceptions caught in my application.

This controller implements an interface `IExceptionLogger`

```
public class ExceptionController : Controller, IExceptionLogger
  {...}
```

which has one method `void LogException(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail);`

I have implemented the method inside the `ExceptionController` too.

```
void IExceptionLogger.LogException(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
 {...}
```

Now I need to call the method `LogException()` from the action `Index` of the `ExceptionController`.

```
public ActionResult Index(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
    {
      // Method must be called here
      return View(exceptionDetail);
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `LogException(exceptionDetail);`?

Comment: I would have tried calling the method there and see what happens...

Comment: Is there any reason why you implemented the interface explicitly?

Comment: What could the method possibly do?  It needs to be part of the `ActionResult` chain or it's no good -- you won't be able to actually return the error view.  You should probably use an action filter -- `HandleErrorAttribute` would be a good place to start; you can set the returned view from an action filter context.

Comment: That method is used to log error in a file

Comment: I was not able to  implement the method Implicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `LogException` is [implemented explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), you have to cast to `IExceptionLogger` before calling it:

```
public ActionResult Index(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
{
    ((IExceptionLogger)exceptionDetail).LogException();

     return View(exceptionDetail);
}
```

To make it work without casting, implement method implicitly:

```
void LogException(ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail)
{
}
```

Comment: See the link under *implemented explicitly*;

Comment: I can't implement the method Implicitly

Comment: Then you have to cast it before calling `LogException`.

Answer (score 0):

Call LogException() directly. Doesn't it work?

Comment: The name 'LogException' does not exist in the current context